# How to hide/unhide codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to hide/unhide a codemirror instance completely.
Is there any predefined method doing that, or do I need to somehow select the div and make it hidden.

Comment: I tried to get it via its ID but it did not work.
cm.getWrapperElement().style.display="none";
works fine.

Comment: That is because CodeMirror removes the original element and replaces it with its own set.

Comment: Yes I know, the div is 'class="CodeMirror cm-s-default" ' but I was not able to hide it. However, it works great with the method mentioned before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

according to the documentation, CodeMirror's main editor object has a method that returns to you the main wrapper DOM element.

```
cm.getWrapperElement()
```

From there, you should be able to just hide the element like you would hide any html element.

Answer (score 7):

Building upon Lochemage's answer, the following code will perform hide/show of Codemirror instance.

```
var cm = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;

//Hide
$(cm.getWrapperElement()).hide();

//Show
$(cm.getWrapperElement()).show();
```

Comment: What is 'cm', could you be specific there too, please?

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
var cm = $('.CodeMirror')[0];
var cm$ = $(cm.getWrapperElement());
//Hide
cm$.hide();
//Show
cm$.show();
```