# Is there a way to make a <td> appear when a button is selected and the <td> display is none? (The <td> will have a codeMirror text area in it)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am having some trouble here. I am developing a button that once selected will run a JavaScript function - ShowColumn() - that will make a table column appear. The table column will at first be hidden - "display:none;" - but once the user selects the button the table column that is hidden will then appear/will be visible. However, this table column will have a codeMirror text area in it. Can this be done? And if so please can someone help? Thanks :)

I have included what I have done so far, as follows:

```html
<head>

<style>
 
.hidden {
   display: none;
}

.visible {
   display: block;
}
 
</style>
 
<script>
 
function ShowColumn() { 
   document.getElementById("Column").className = "visible";
}
 
</script>

<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="mode/clike/clike.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="mode/xml/xml.js"><!-- needed for htmlmixed --></script>
<script src="mode/css/css.js"></script>
<link href="theme/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme/mdn-like.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>
    .CodeMirror {
        border:none;
        width:100%;
        height:451px;
        margin-left:100;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="ShowColumn()">Click me</button>
<table>
<tr>
<td>

 <textarea id="code2" name="code2" style="padding-top:0px; border:none; padding-left:300px;" >
        some css code will be here....
    <textarea>
 
<select style="height:46px; width:100%; margin:0px; position:relative; left:0%;">
  <option value="volvo">index.html</option>
  <option value="saab">another_page.html</option>
  <option value="mercedes">placeholder_page.html</option>
  <option value="audi">other.html</option>
</select>
<script> 
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code2"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/css",
    lineWrapping: true,
    theme: 'default',
  });
</script>


</td>
<td id="Column" class="hidden">

  <textarea id="code2" name="code2" style="padding-top:0px; border:none; padding-left:300px;" > 
    some css code will be here....
  </textarea> 

   <select style="height:46px; width:100%; margin:0px; position:relative; left:0%;">
  <option value="volvo">index.html</option>
  <option value="saab">another_page.html</option>
  <option value="mercedes">placeholder_page.html</option>
  <option value="audi">other.html</option>
</select>
<script> 
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code2"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/css",
    lineWrapping: true,
    theme: 'default',
  });
</script>

</td>
<td>


 <iframe src="" style="height:550px; width:100%;"></iframe>


</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
```

I have done a lot of research and I haven't come up with any solution to my problem. Can this be done with JavaScript and HTML alone? Or do I have to incorporate another language into the system in order to make the hidden column visible? Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: jQuery .show() and .hide() work great, but I'm not sure why what you have doesn't work?

Comment: This is what jQuery, CSS, and DOM manipulation were born for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response :) What is DOM manipulation? And please can you show me how to incorporate it into my code? Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Thanks @godmode, whenever I use the jQuery .show() and/or .hide() the content within the table column is hidden, and not the actual table column itself. Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/85yL2gx6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery has functions `show`, `hide` and `toggle` which can help you achieve what you want. Initially, the table-column is hidden using `class="hide"`. Using the `toggle()` function it can be shown/hidden as the button is pressed.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85yL2gx6/3/

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="ShowTable()">Display Table</button>
  <button onclick="ShowColumn()">Display Column</button>

  <table id="hiddenTable" class='show'>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <textarea>Write something here....</textarea>
       </td>
      <td id="hiddenColumn" class='hide'>
         <textarea>Write something here....</textarea>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script type="text/Javascript">
    function ShowColumn()
    {  
      $("#hiddenColumn").toggle();
    }
      
    function ShowTable()
    {
      $("#hiddenTable").toggle();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

**Edit - Codemirror**
Lucky for you, I implemented a similar thing few days back and here's the magic trick! To fetch the codemirror instance you need to do:

```js
var cm = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
```

Use the following snippet for button click:

```js
var cm = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;

// Hide
$(cm.getWrapperElement()).hide();
    
// Show
$(cm.getWrapperElement()).show();
```

Reference: [How to hide/unhide codemirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581194/how-to-hide-unhide-codemirror/30873800#30873800)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to manage styles using JQuery and write this kind of code :

```
$('#hiddenColumn').show();
$('#hiddenColumn').hide();
```

Dont forget to hide all cells from your second column.

You can see an exemple here : 
https://jsfiddle.net/0rn3oq51/

Comment: Thanks for the response @MartinDonies, I was wondering if you could please put your coding magic in practise to help me find a new answer to my new (edited) question above. Thanks for the help